# Why does this boost transform operation get the 2nd element wrong?

Tags: c++, boost

This *might* be related to [possible bug in boost transformed adaptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22251746/possible-bug-in-boost-transformed-adaptor?rq=1) but I'm not sure...

I am trying to create a function that that returns a transformed range using `boost::adaptors::transformed`. To do this I adapted [the example on the boost doc website](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/transformed.html), and did the following:

```
#include <boost/range/adaptor/transformed.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
struct double_int
{
    typedef int result_type;
    int operator()(int x) const { return 2 * x; }
};

boost::transformed_range<double_int, std::vector<int>> Fun(std::vector<int> input)
{
    return input | boost::adaptors::transformed(double_int());
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> input {0, 1, 2, 3};

    for (auto elem : Fun(input))
        std::cout << elem;

    return 0;
}
```

The expected output of this program is `0, 2, 4, 6`, but instead I get this:

> 0046

It's getting the 2nd number wrong! Why?

I am using `boost 1.55` with `gcc 4.8.1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have undefined behaviour. You passed `input` into the function by value, and boost range takes it by reference. When you are using the returned range, it hold a reference to a destroyed vector and caused undefined behaviour.

[This works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/31a6c36efff7609e)

```
#include <boost/range/adaptor/transformed.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
struct double_int
{
    typedef int result_type;
    int operator()(int x) const { return 2 * x; }
};

boost::transformed_range<double_int, std::vector<int>>
       Fun(std::vector<int> &input) // takes reference
{
    return input | boost::adaptors::transformed(double_int());
}

int main()
{

    std::vector<int> input {0, 1,2,3,4};
    for (auto elem : Fun(input))
        std::cout << elem;

    return 0;
}
```